# How can I find which font unicode-math is using for a particular symbol?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, unicode-math

The following MWE produces a blank document, as the default font does not contain `⟿`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\(⟿\)
\end{document}
```

Adding `\usepackage{unicode-math}` solves the issue:

[image: Unicode-math]

How can I get this arrow without using unicode-math? I could prefix the character with `\fontspec{some font}`, but I don't know which font gives this particular look; other fonts that I tried looked rather different (for example with Asana Math):

[image: Asana math]

How do I get the curly arrow pictured above without loading unicode-math?

EDIT: Explicitly selecting Latin Modern Math gives me a blank document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\fontspec{Latin Modern Math}⟿
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you don't specify any math font, the default Latin Modern Math is used.

Comment: @egreg That's surprising: why would unicode-math make a difference then? Why do I get a blank document when I don't load it?

Comment: Because if you don't load `unicode-math`, the standard math fonts are used and `⟿` corresponds to nothing.

Comment: I don't understand: wouldn't explicitly selecting the Latin Modern Math font load it?

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow you.

Comment: @egreg Sorry, I must have been unclear. From what you say, I gather that since I didn't specify a math font after loading the unicode-math, the font being used to display the arrow in the first picture is Latin Modern Math. If this assumption is correct, then I would expect that adding `\fontspec{Latin Modern Math}` to my document, regardless of whether unicode-math is used, would cause the arrow to be displayed as in my first picture. This is however not the case.

Comment: In my experiment, your final example prints the squiggly arrow.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't for me. Do you have ideas of what could cause this?

Comment: Conflicting copies of the font, maybe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a Unicode Math font just like any ordinary font. On my system, the `⟿` character is present in several fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface{\applesymbols}{Apple Symbols}
\newfontface{\asanamath}{Asana Math}
\newfontface{\dejavusans}{DejaVu Sans}
\newfontface{\dejavuserif}{DejaVu Serif}
\newfontface{\fdsymbol}{FdSymbol}
\newfontface{\freeserif}{FreeSerif}
\newfontface{\latinmodernmath}{Latin Modern Math}
\newfontface{\mdsymbol}{MdSymbol}
\newfontface{\STIX}{STIX} % also Math
\newfontface{\symbola}{Symbola}
\newfontface{\texgyremath}{TeX Gyre Bonum Math}
\newfontface{\texgyremath}{TeX Gyre DejaVu Math}
\newfontface{\texgyremath}{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\newfontface{\texgyremath}{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\newfontface{\texgyremath}{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\newfontface{\XITS}{XITS} % also Math

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\applesymbols ⟿  & Apple Symbols \\
\asanamath ⟿  & Asana Math \\
\dejavusans ⟿  & DejaVu Sans \\
\dejavuserif ⟿  & DejaVu Serif \\
\fdsymbol ⟿  & FdSymbol \\
\freeserif ⟿  & FreeSerif \\
\latinmodernmath ⟿  & Latin Modern Math \\
\mdsymbol ⟿  & MdSymbol \\
\STIX ⟿  & STIX \\ % also Math
\symbola ⟿  & Symbola \\
\texgyremath ⟿  & TeX Gyre Bonum Math \\
\texgyremath ⟿  & TeX Gyre DejaVu Math \\
\texgyremath ⟿  & TeX Gyre Pagella Math \\
\texgyremath ⟿  & TeX Gyre Schola Math \\
\texgyremath ⟿  & TeX Gyre Termes Math \\
\XITS ⟿  & XITS \\ % also Math
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Choose the one you prefer. Once you have chosen the best one for your taste, you can do something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newfontface{\squigglefont}{Apple Symbols}[Scale=1.5]

\newunicodechar{⟿}{{\squigglefont⟿}}

\begin{document}

Here is the squiggle ⟿ in a different font
than the main one.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Turned out that this arrow was added semi-recently to Latin Modern Math, and I had multiple conflicting copies of the font (as you guessed a while ago).

Comment: Btw, did you really mean to declare `\texgyremath` five times in your example?

Comment: @Clément No, I forgot to add suffixes. I'll fix.